# How to validate if one field is set then another field is require in Codeigniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation

I have two input fields for the users to input a range of year.  If the user didn't enter anything, the page will run a default setting.  If the user enter one of the field, he is required to enter the other field as well to get pass the validation.

Also I saved the rules as an array and put into application/config/form_validation.php. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do a custom check. See the information about [CallBacks on the CI Form Validation page](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks). So you would set the call bak for field one. In the called back function you would implement your rules and return back a TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: I'd read the callback documentation, but it's show you to do it in the controller, how do I do this in config's form_validation.php file instead?

Comment: The callback function is just part of the validation array. You put it into the form_validation.php file just like any other rule and when you call run, it will callback to your function.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your form validation inside of an if `strlen($_POST['field_1'])>0` or if `isset($_POST['field_1'])` statement so that it only runs if there is a value within field_1.

```
if(isset($_POST['field_1'])){
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('field_1', 'Field 1', '');
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('field_2', 'Field 2', 'required');

    if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
          $errors = validation_errors();
    } else {

        //do your thing

     }
}
```

Put this in your controller.